# algunas dudas sobre agregación Bootsrap (bagging)

Tags: machine-learning

tengo una duda acerca de  la aplicación del bagging. Cuando este se aplica imaginemos en una regresión lineal, este crea muchos modelos que son resultado de muestrear una cierta cantidad de veces una data de entrenamiento. Ahora según entiendo la predicción final seria el promedio de todas las perdiciones resultantes de todos los modelos hallados. Imaginemos que obtuve los modelos:

```
y'(1) = ax1+bx2+c,  
y'(2) = dx1+ex2+f,  
y'(3) = gx1+hx2+i 
.... etc
```

entonces el modelo resultante de haber aplicado ese bagging en resumen seria

```
y' = promedio(a,d,g...)x1 + promedio(b,e,h...)x2 + promedio(c,f,i...) ??????
```

Y si quisiera aplicarlo en un perceptrón, para predecir algo, la función que me represente esa red neuronal tendría como pesos sinápticos finales al promedio de todos los pesos de todos los perceptrones hallados por el bagging?? Seria lo mismo para clasificación?? quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, esa es una pregunta complicada de inteligencia artificial, no estoy seguro si esta relacionada con StackOverflow, ¿has intentado programar la red neuronal?

Comment: También puedes buscar en [Artificial Inteligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning?sort=votes&pageSize=15)

Comment: Mi interés se centraba en el efecto del bagging en las salidas de las funciones de machine learning, estoy trabajando con r project, haré una prueba con los pesos de una red en una data pequeña. Gracias de todas maneras